# Scale Animation on Compound Drawables Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, android-selector

I have a `RadioButton` with its `drawableTop` set to a `LayerList`. That `LayerList` looks like this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/image_radio_button_bg_selector" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/imageRadioButtonDrawableSize"
                android:height="@dimen/imageRadioButtonDrawableSize" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/imageRadioButtonDrawableRadius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
<layer-list>
```

I want to be able to animate this drawable when `RadioButton` is checked or unchecked. Drawable needs to scale from 50% to 100% when RadioButton is checked and vice versa otherwise. Is there a way to add animations in compound drawable? Specially when drawable is driven by `Color Selector` and not by `Drawable Selector`. (`image_radio_button_bg_selector` in my case)

That color selector looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in res/anim/scale.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"     // anchor point in x-axis->
        android:pivotY="50%"     // anchor point in x-axis
        android:fromYScale="0.5" // from size Y axis
        android:fromXScale="0.5" // from size X axis
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
        android:toYScale="1.0"   // to size Y axis
        android:toXScale="1.0"   // to size X axis
        android:duration="250"/> // time of duration in milliseconds

</set>
```

Usage in the activity file

```
RadioGroup rGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
RadioButton checkedRadioButton =(RadioButton)rGroup.findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
       Animation bulge = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.scale);
                        checkedRadioButton.startAnimation(bulge);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your effort but this will animate the `RadioButton` and not just the drawable.